Rate of convergence (Berry-Esseen theorem) for the sum of an asymptotically normal random number of random variables?
Let $\{X_i, i \geq 1\}$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with finite mean and variance.
Let $M_t$ be a non-negative, integer-valued random variable that is independent from $\{X_i\}$.
Suppose that $M_t$ is asymptotically normal (as $t \to \infty$), with convergence rate $o(t^d$).
What conclusion(s) can be drawn about the rate of convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^{M_t} X_i$ to normality?
Special case of interest: $M_t$ as a (counting) renewal process.

Details
Robbins (1948) established the following seminal result on the sum of an asymptotically normal number of random variables (as quoted by Chen et al, 2011, equation 10.38).

Let $\{X_i, i \geq 1\}$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with $EX_i = \mu$ and $\text{Var}(X_i) = \sigma^2$, and let $\{N_n, n \geq 1\}$ be a sequence of non-negative integer-valued random variables that are independent of $\{X_i, i \geq 1\}$. Assume for each $n = 1, 2, \dots$ that $EN_n^2 < \infty$ and
$$
  \frac{N_n - EN_n}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(N_n)}} \xrightarrow{\quad d \quad} \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
where $\xrightarrow{\,d\,}$ denotes convergence in distribution and $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is the normal distribution with mean 0, variance 1.
Then
$$
  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N_n} X_i - (EN_n)\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2EN_n + \mu^2\text{Var}(N_n)}} \xrightarrow{\quad d \quad} \mathcal{N}(0,1)
\tag{1}
$$

Now suppose that $N_n \equiv N_{n(t)} \equiv M_t$ is a renewal process. It is well-known that a renewal process is asymptotically normal. Indeed a rate of convergence can be found, for example (Englund, 1980, as quoted by Reinert & Yang, 2018)

Let $Z$, $Z_i$, $i=1, 2, \dots$ be independent, identically distributed, non-negative random variables with positive mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$, and let
$$
  M_t = \max\left\{ n : \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i < t \right\}
$$
If $\gamma := E\lvert Z - \mu \vert^3 < \infty$ then
$$
  \sup_{n=0,1,\dots}
  \left\lvert
    P(M_t < n) - \Phi\left( \frac{(n\mu - t)\sqrt{\mu}}{\sigma\sqrt{t}} \right)
  \right\rvert
  \leq
  4 \left( \frac{\gamma}{\sigma} \right)^3 \left( \frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{\sqrt{t}} \right)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\tag{2}
$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function for the standard normal distribution.

How can (2), or similar results, be used to put a rate of convergence on (1)? (A Berry-Esseen theorem)?
What I have tried
Chen et al (2011, Theorem 10.6) obtained

Let $\{X_i, i \geq 1\}$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with $EX_i = \mu$, $\text{Var}(X_i) = \sigma^2$, $E\lvert X_i \rvert^3 < \infty$, and $\{Y_i, i \geq 1\}$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with $EY_i = \nu$, $\text{Var}(X_i) = \tau^2$, $E\lvert Y_i \rvert^3 < \infty$, with $\{X_i, i \geq 1\}$ and $\{Y_i, i \geq 1\}$ independent. If $N_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$ then there exists a universal constant $C$ such that
$$
  \sup_{z\in\mathbb{R}}
  \left\lvert
    P\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N_n} X_i - n\mu\nu}{\sqrt{n(\nu \sigma^2 + \tau^2\mu^2)}} \leq z \right) - \Phi(z)
  \right\rvert
  \leq
  C n^{-1/2}
  \left(
    \frac{\tau^2}{\nu^2} + \frac{EY_1^3}{\tau^3} + \frac{E\lvert X_1|^3}{\nu^{1/2}\sigma^3} + \frac{\sigma}{\mu\sqrt{\nu}}
  \right)
$$

Comparing this result with Robbins (1948) makes me think that the conditions on $\{Y_i, i \geq 1\}$ are all about ensuring that $N_n$ is asymptotically normal. Thus, if asymptotic normality of  $N_{n(t)}$ is taken as an input then everything should still work. However I can't see how to refactor the proof appropriately.
(I have otherwise sought to express $N_{n(t)}$ as a sum $N_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$ as per the conditions.)
References
Chen, Louis H.Y.; Goldstein, Larry; Shao, Qi-Man (2011). Normal Approximation by Stein’s Method, Springer-Verlag, Berlin Heidelberg.
Englund, G. (1980). Remainder term estimate for the asymptotic
normality of the number of renewals. Journal of Applied Probability,
17(4), 1108-1113.
Reinert, Gesine; Yang, Ce (2018). A Bound on the Rate of Convergence in the Central Limit Theorem for Renewal Processes under Second Moment Conditions. arXiv:1807.08672
Robbins, Herbert (1948, December). The asymptotic distribution of the sum of a random number of random variables, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 54(12): 1151-1161

I learned that there is older literature on the sum of a random number of random variables that can be put to work ... and that there are opportunities for going further.
The following is from Korolev (1989, Theorem 1 and Remark 3). Note: This is a tiny portion of the results that they established.

Let $\{X_i\}$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with $EX_i = \mu$, $\text{Var}(X_i) = \sigma^2$, $E\lvert X_i - \mu \rvert^3 = \kappa^3$. Let $N$ be a non-negative integer-valued random variable, independent from $\{X_i\}$.
Let $S_N = X_1 + \cdots + X_N$, and define
$$
  \Delta = \sup_{x} \left\lvert
    P\left(
      \frac{S_N - ES_N}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(S_N)}}
      \leq
      z
    \right)
    -
    \Phi(z)
  \right\rvert
$$
Then
$$
  \Delta \leq
  3.8696\frac{\kappa^3}{\sqrt{EN}\sigma^3} +
  1.0395\frac{E\lvert N - EN\rvert}{EN} +
  0.2420\frac{\mu^2 \text{Var}(N)}{\sigma^2 EN}
$$

Now if $N \equiv N(t)$ is a renewal process where the inter-arrival times have mean $\nu$ and variance $\tau^2 < \infty$ then
$$\begin{align*}
  \frac{EN(t)}{t} &\to \frac{1}{\nu}
&&\text{and}&
  \frac{\text{Var}(N(t))}{t} &\to \frac{\tau^2}{\nu^3}
\end{align*}$$
by Blackwell's theorem and successors (for example Daly, 1978).
Finally, the limit of convergence in distribution is unique, so the above convergence can be put in parallel with the convergence deduced via Robbins (1948) in the original post. Therefore a rate of convergence of $o(^{-1/2})$ can be deduced.
The research into rates of convergence for random sums of random variables remains active - see for example
Döbler (2015, Theorem 2.5 especially) and Sunklodas (2017 - note that this uses a different metric).
The intriguing aspect is that - based on a superficial reading - the rates of convergence can be improved(?)/tuned(?) to the distribution of $N$ - see for example other works by Sunklodas.
However, I was unable to find a result which explicitly handled the case of $N(t)$ arising from a renewal process.
References
Daley, D.J., Mohan, N.R. (1978): Asymptotic Behaviour of the Variance of Renewal
Processes and Random Walks. The Annals of Probability 6(3), 516–521
Döbler, Christian (2015): New Berry-Esseen and Wasserstein bounds in the CLT for non-randomly centered random sums by probabilistic methods. ALEA, Lat. Am. J. Probab. Math. Stat. 12 (2), 863–902
Korolev, V. Yu (1989): On the accuracy of normal approximation for the distributions of sums of a random number of independent random variables. Theory of Probability
& Its Applications 33(3), 540–544
Sunklodas, Jonas Kazys (2017, April). On the rate of convergence in the global central limit theorem for random sums of independent random variables. Lithuanian Mathematical Journal, 57(2), 244–258
